# sqlite SELECT in Statement does not retrieve any row

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, select, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Working on an application for Backberry, I have the following issue dealing with sqlite database.

This statement works fine in sqlite manager and retrieves the corresponding data in the database :

```
SELECT Z_PK,Z_NAME,Z_STATUS from ZTABLE WHERE Z_PK=1
```

Now if I create an instance of net.rim.device.api.database.Statement like this :

```
Statement statement = this.db.createStatement("SELECT Z_PK,Z_NAME,Z_STATUS FROM ZTABLE WHERE Z_PK=?1"); 
statement.prepare();                
statement.bind(1, id.intValue());
Cursor cursor = statement.getCursor();              
Row row = cursor.getRow();
```

the variable row is null whereas this.db is well initialized (it works for an INSERT statement) ; moreover id is also well initialized with value 1.

I cannot see what is different compared to the sqlite sample project and why this does not work as it should.

Can anybody help me please ? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I just missed the small but very important line with the call to next() :

```
Cursor cursor = statement.getCursor();
if(cursor.next())
{
    Row row = cursor.getRow();
    ...
```